# Why doesn't Math.Round() support float?

Tags: c#, math

Why doesn't `Math.Round()` support `float`?

**edit:**

People should not be voting to close this. It is **not** opinion based. As stated in the comments below, there is a real technical reason that `Math.Round` does not return an int, which is that large floating point numbers cannot be stored in an integer of similar size without overflowing.

So I'm asking if there is actually a reason that `float` overloads are not included in `Math.Round`, `Math.Ceil`, etc..

The answer may be no, but that doesn't mean this question is opinion based.

Comment: It is pretty questionable that it supports *double*, given that the result is never accurate.  You'd just get 8 more random digits with *float*.  Not otherwise an issue since just about any language supports an implicit conversion from float to double.

Comment: The real question is: __Why doesn't it return `ìnt`?__

Comment: @TaW I think the answer to that is pretty straight forward though: A floating point number can hold much larger values than similarly-sized integers. So rounding a float to an int would cause overflow with large numbers.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by "support."

When you attempt to call a method that has overloads with a type it doesn't directly support (such as calling `Math.Round(float)`), it will try to determine the best version to call (if any).  How this is done is discussed at length in section 7.5.3 of the C# Language Specification 5.0.

Since `float` can be [implicitly converted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) to [a `double`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx), this means that [`Math.Round(Double)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wyk4d9cy(v=vs.110).aspx) will be called.

However, that version also returns a `double` back, so you would have to [explicitly cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx) the results to a `float` if that's what you want.